# phonegap - scrolling not working in android devices

Tags: android, cordova, scroll

I developed a phonegap app that works perfectly on ios devices.
When I tested it on android devices I noticed that I can't scroll the screen (on specific devices - like galaxy s2).
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess this is running a lower version of Android ... in the older versions of android you can't scroll inside a div within the cordova framework. It's very frustraiting. The only way to achieve this is to install a library such as iscroll.  http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5